# Windows batch file script IF does not work

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have tried to make Windows batch file that blinking the word "Wait" & "Wait..". I tried the following code:

```
@Echo OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
SET p=-1
set num=2
set st[1]=Wait
set st[2]=Wait..
set st[3]=eer

:LOOP

if /i %num% equ 1 (
set num=2
) else (
set num=1
)
<nul set /P "=!st[%num%]!!CR!"

TIMEOUT /T 1 >NUL






GOTO :LOOP
```

The problem here, the `IF` seems to be worked only one time. i.e running the batch makes it prompt "Wait" only one time, then "Wait.." forever. What is the mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is not the `if` (that works as intended), your problem are the spaces that should delete/overwrite the dots.

```
set "st[1]=Wait  "
set "st[2]=Wait.."
```